# What is the right article a or an for structural engineering?

Tags: articles

What is the right article for the below sentence

Consultant agrees to execute an structural engineering.
Consultant agrees to execute a structural engineering.

Comment: Why oh why is this here?

Comment: And now we have an answer. Kinda makes me wish questions were closed by default and people voted to open them.

Comment: I would like to know what is the correct article to use. Is it a or an? Thank you.

Comment: Mel, welcome to the ELU :-) we have a sister site: [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) and your question might be better suited for that one. @Area51DetectiveFiction - can we migrate it there?

Comment: @Lucky: [You tell me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Hi Mel, welcome to EL&U. According to the norms of this site, questions are off-topic if they are answerable using general reference. If the asker feels this doesn't apply to their question, a good way to prove it is to include links to the gen-ref sites and explain why that doesn't help them.

Comment: Btw, it's "Consultant agrees to execute a structural engineering project (or something)." It's beyond me why any consultant would agree to that.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Well, I'm not sure (the question is not well-asked, but I would like to help the OP) - so I guess I'll "let someone else who is sure do that". Thanks for the link :-)

Comment: Why do you want to execute a structural engineer?  (Granted, I've been tempted to beat up a few over the years, but I restrained myself.)

Comment: Please go to English Language Learners Stack Exchange.  There you will learn the very basic rule about the article "a" vs "an" -- "a" should be used before a consonant sound, "an" before a vowel sound.

Answer (score 0):

Neither make sense, sorry. I do not think you know what 'structural engineering' means in this context.

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). You obviously had a good intention to help the OP, but if a question is not suited for ELU, sometimes it's better not to answer it (this is recommended by the [help centre](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) guidelines).